# Get the major, minor, and UUID of an iBeacon discreetly on Oreo

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-8.0-oreo

I have been using a background service to get these values on android 7. I know it is possible to do the same on android 8 by using a foreground service or an activity. 
But is it possible to get these values in an unobtrusive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing changes in Android 8 with respect to the ability to read beacon identifiers.  You can still get the UUID, major and minor of an iBeacon unobtrusively.  The only thing that changes is that you can no longer do this (or run any other code) in a long-running background service.

I wrote a blog post with full details about what changes here: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8